# Retag [retain-cycle] Swift questions to [strong-reference-cycle]?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I noticed a large number of [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) questions with the [retain-cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/retain-cycle) tag. But “retain cycle” is a term dating back to manual-retain-release (MRR) code, where two objects called [`retain`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1571946-retain) of the other, only calling [`release`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1571957-release) of the other when being deallocated (and with the two objects having retained the other, it results in a cycle, where neither can be deallocated).

But, in automatic reference counting (ARC), it is not a “retain cycle”, but rather a “strong reference cycle” (where two or more objects have strong references to each other, resulting in an analogous “cycle”). In Apple’s original [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) they refer to strong reference cycles as being “previously known as retain cycles”. When ARC was introduced in 2011, Apple explicitly wanted to have people stop thinking in terms of “retain counts” and instead reason about the presence or absence of “strong references”.

FWIW, Swift never really used `retain` and `release`. It uses ARC; see [The Swift Programming Language: Automatic Reference Counting](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/automaticreferencecounting). (Yes, Swift can interact with “unmanaged” objects, but I could not find [retain-cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/retain-cycle) questions that were dealing with unmanaged objects; all the questions I saw were all in regards to ARC.) Even in Objective-C, MRR is exceptionally rare nowadays.

I can understand some caution regarding Objective-C questions (even though most of those are incorrectly tagged, too). But I might propose that we consider having [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) questions tagged with [retain-cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/retain-cycle) be retagged with [strong-reference-cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/strong-reference-cycle).